# How can I make a python3 program not crash if it tries to add a string and a number together

Tags: python, python-3.x

Source code

---

```
import sys
hi = input("Input a number ")
yo = input("Input a second number ")

total = int(hi) + int(yo)

def convertStr(s):

        try:
            ret = int(s)
            print(int(total))

        except ValueError:

            ret = str(total)
            print("There was an error")


convertStr(total)
```

How can I make it so that the python can add two inputs together but not crash when I put a string in one of the values?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please take the time to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [what can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  As it is written your question does not make a lot of sense.  You are converting both inputs to integers before you call `convertStr` so there is no error checking on the part that matters, only later when you try to cast `total` which is already an integer to another integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your function `convertStr(s)` on input `hi` and `yo`. If input is not a number then ask again for input.